# Is this shuffle random by property

Tags: random

```
def shuffle(deck):
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        idxToPlaceHere = randint(i, len(deck) -1)
        swap(deck, i, idxToPlaceHere);
```

I know theres a standard random shuffle algo on here among other sites, but for some reason this is the natural way I write shuffle.  It seems to me to maintain (len-1)! possibilities.  I'm new at this stuff though so can someone please confirm whether or not this is random so I know if I must memorize the standard way of doing it so as to not bomb my interview.  Thanks.

Comment: What is your question yes it randoms.

Comment: I did a test for shuffling array [1,2,3] 100,000 times.  The counts were as follows 16724
16693
16510
16795
16649
16629

Comment: thats random right?

Comment: Yes it is random.

Comment: Did my answer fit your question ? If yes mark it as accepted pls.

Answer (score 0):

You use len-1 out of the following reason:

You have a deck with 3 cards, they are storred inside an array:

```
deck = {
  0 = "card 1",
  1 = "card 2",
  2 = "card 3"
}
```

So `len(deck)` returns the ammount of elements, in this case 3. Inside your for loop you have the index `i`.

The keys start with 0 so your variable `i` will be `0, 1, 2`

```
randint(startIndex, endIndex)
```

randint calculates a random number between the `startIndex` and the `endIndex`. Without `len-1` it would be a number between 0 and 3.

The problem is you dont have an key 3 in your array, cause your array start from 0. Thats why u use `len-1`, that way you have the real last possible key.